# Datatable from lumen api to laravel application not working

Tags: laravel, api, lumen

I want to send the result of `return Datatables::of(DB::table('ride'))->make(true);` from lumen api to laravel application called by `GuzzleHttp\Client client`. I can display data in laravel application but can't sort or search. The request is going to the API but nothing is happening.

I think the request sent by Guzzle client is not the being received by the `Lumen API` :

API code :

```
public function rides(Request $request){
   return Datatables::of(DB::table('ride'))->make(true);
}
```

Laravel Application code :

```
$resultat = $client_ppm->request('get', $url_, [
            'form_params' => $datafield_array,
            'headers' => [
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token,
                'Content-type' => 'application/json',
                'Accept' => 'application/json',
                'from' => 'portail'
             ]
           ]);

return $resultat->getBody();
```

Comment: just dd($resultat) and see what comes.

Comment: nothing t happend :s

Comment: any helps plz  thanks

Comment: Please share your Route code.

Comment: in Lumen : 
$router->get('rides', 'RideController@rides');
in web app  : 
Route::get('/admin/getRides', 'RideController@rides');